# How to use map to get specific properties from array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have following part of code: I would like to create new Array of objects based on this `arr` but only with `age` and `id` property

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: "A",
    age: 1,
    id: 11,
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    age: 2,
    id: 22,
  },
  {
    name: "C",
    age: 3,
    id: 33,
  },
  {
    name: "D",
    age: 4,
    id: 44,
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question Try this:

```
var newArr=arr.map(item=>{
return  {
    id:item.id,
    age :item.age
  } 
})
```

Comment: If that what you search please vote it and thanks